# How to access struct put into an array as pointer

Tags: c

How to access a struct that is put into an array as pointer?

How to access the `boote` array propertly? I tried also using `boot = *boote[i];`

```
typedef struct boot {
   char name[30];
} Boot;

Boot *boote[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};

Boot boot;

scanf("%s", boot.name);

boote[0] = &boot;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (boote[i]->name != NULL) {
         printf("%s", boote[i]->name ); // why is it empty
      }
}
```

---

Update:

It seems I put a reference to a local function `boot` into global `boote`.

So how can I store actual `boot` in `boote`, like boote[0] = boot; Gives me an error

Comment: I don't know how this compiled for you, I got an error on the 'boot.name = "abc";' assignment. And that is correct, since boot.name is a character array while "abc" is a const pointer. If you change to use strcpy then you will get the expected output.

Comment: Please see the edit, I just simplified my code here

Comment: When `i > 0` you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: How to fix that? And why is there no value in ->name even though I set it?

Comment: To fix that, take out your loop and do `printf("%s", boote[0]->name);`. You've only created one Boot, how do you expect to print 3 of them.

Comment: Yes but later I will have more...

Comment: For this example, it's simpler to change boot.name to be a pointer and initialise it to the string constants.

Comment: What does it mean when I get output for `boote[i]->name` as ���

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was referencing an boot that was local. Now I am using `Boot boote[8];` and storing a created boot directly in boote. Now it works.

Comment: The real problem was that you didn't provide the original code, which caused a lot of guetimates on our side. It was not clear from your example that 'boot' was local. You didn't even include your 'main' function and the posted code was not even compilable.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to C. I will improve my questions. Thank you

Comment: It's OK - it looks like the brainstorming helped you to find the problem faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly using C, then this:

```
boot.name = "abc";
```

should be:

```
strcpy(boot.name, "abc");
```

Don't name this variable boot; the struct is named boot:

```
typedef struct boot {
   char name[30];
} Boot;
Boot boot; /* Should be named boot1, ETC. because you have typedef struct boot above */
```

In the for loop, you also need to check to make sure both `boote[i]` and `boote[i]->name` are non-NULL.

Comment: The variable name `boot` does not clash with the struct tag `boot`, although I agree that it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use strcpy in C.strcpy(boot.name,"abc")

Yet another thing:

```
if (boote[i] != NULL) {
```

Here is the code that I've just tested and it worked as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct boot {
   char name[30];
} Boot;

Boot *boote[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};

Boot boot;

int main() {
scanf("%s", boot.name);

boote[0] = &boot;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (boote[i] != NULL) {
         printf("%s", boote[i]->name ); // why is it empty
      }
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what OS you use, but on Linux I've used the following to compile/run:

```
cc -o prog -std=c99 prog.c
chmod +x prog
./prog
```

Output:
    abc

Where abc is a string that I've entered from stdin

Comment: it is not about the string, as I get it correctly via scanf

Comment: can you print boot.name right after scanf? We need to make sure that you're actually getting something from input.

Comment: yes the input is there, I print it right after the input with `printf("%s", boot.name);`

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the `strcpy` thing, the way you access the struct is ok, in fact the "abc" is being printed. However, in the `for` loop you're looping over `bootie[1]` and `bootie[2]` which are not assigned yet, therefore it doesn't print anything.

Comment: But it does not event print the boote[0] name property

Comment: Yes it does, check again ;)

Comment: It didn't for me.. the segmentation fault happens, before there's any terminal output, because of lack of a \n in the printf format string there's no flushing of stdout buffer

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the origonally posted code example by

1) changing boot.name to be char *
2) initialising the whole array, not just first element
Now there's output

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct boot {
   char *name;
} Boot;

Boot *boote[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
Boot boot;

int main (int arc, char **agv) {
    boot.name = "abc";

    boote[0] = &boot; boote[1] = &boot; boote[2] = &boot;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       if (boote[i]->name != NULL) {
           printf("%s", boote[i]->name ); // why is it empty
       }
    }
}

$ gcc -std=c99 ex.c
$ ./a.out
abcabcabc$
```

Comment: changing to `char *name;` leads to RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault:

Comment: Which is why, I did 2)  initialise every element of array.. see abcabcabc, not just 1 abc?

Comment: You could keep boot in local function but declare it static.  `static Boot boot` and similarly for any strings you define locally.  To dynamically allocate the strings, you can : `boot.name = strdup( "silly string");`